# Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.for msg.sender and adress 0

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft, contract

```
    // create the fllow to transform the ownership of the nft
    //from the item owner(seller) to the contract that will transact to the buyer
    IERC721(nftcontract).transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),tokenId);

    //after the marketitem is created
    //the market item creation is an event executed by this contract so we must emit it so that the details of the market item will be listned to or used
    emit MarketItemcreated(
     ItemId,
     nftcontract,//the nft because the nft contract address means the nft created
     tokenId,
     msg.sender,//seller is the msg.sender                              // we don't do payable because we emit only the details of the cretaedmarketid (what the market id contain)
     address(0),//no one yet own this nft
     price,
    false//not yet solde    
    );
}
```

i'am facing the problem in  msg.sender and adress 0 i don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are not modified the function as `payable`. You are not showing the full code, I think the code that you posted is inside a function and this function has to be marked as `payable`. if this is not the case, share the full function code please. A common mistake is not to wrap `msg.sender` with `payable(msg.sender)`. because since solidity 0.6.0 `msg.sender` is not payable any more.